# How to define a custom routedeventargs in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a need to define a custom routedeventarg in F# (to be used by both C# code and F# code).

In C#, I have defined the following

```cs
public class NewTranscriptEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
    {
        private readonly string appendtext;
        public string AppendText
        {
            get { return appendtext; }
        }

        public NewTranscriptEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, string appendtext) : base(routedEvent)
        {
            this.appendtext = appendtext;
        }
    }
```

I have no good idea on how this would be translated into F#.

Ultimately, the custom NewTranscriptEventArgs will be sent to the F# back-end by:

```ml
<i:EventTrigger EventName="NewTranscript">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding NewTranscript}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to run the code, but this is a literal translation to F#:

```ml
type NewTranscriptEventArgs(routedEvent, appendText : string) =
    inherit RoutedEventArgs(routedEvent)
    member _.AppendText = appendText
```

Comment: Code works perfectly in C# (as well as F#)!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh! How simple:

```
type NewTranscriptEventArgs(r:RoutedEvent, appendText: string ) = 
        inherit RoutedEventArgs(r)
        member this.AppendText = appendText
```

Comment: Hah, that's funny. I think we both hit enter at the same time. :)